# combine into a data frame vectors of different length but preserving the order

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a character vector, of the following form:

```
vv<-c(1,2,"c", "2%", 3, "b", "4%")  # original vector
```

From this vector I created some new vectors according to the following lines of code:

```
# original vector     
vv<-c(1,2,"c", "2%", 3, "b", "4%") 

# vector without the characters , i.e the c and b 
vv1<-vv[-grep("[a-zA-Z]", vv)]                 

# Steps to create the vector of "integers"
strip_percents <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", vv1))      
no_percents <- as.numeric(vv1[-grep("%", vv1)])    

# Vector that collects the strings 
strings_vv1 <- vv[grep("[a-zA-Z]", vv)]           


# Vector the collects the percentage numbers 
perce_vv1 <-vv1[grep("%", vv1)]
perce_vv1 <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", perce_vv1))/100
```

My purpose is to combine all these vectors and create a dataframe, **but** following the structure/order of the original vector. In other words, I want to fill the dataframe with NAs in "right place". So, for example, my data frame I want to look like this:

```
df<-data.frame(original=vv, numerics=c(1,2,NA,0.02,3,NA,0.04), integers=c(1,2,NA,NA,3,NA,NA), characters=c(NA,NA,"c",NA,NA,"b",NA))



original numerics integers characters
1        1     1.00        1       <NA>
2        2     2.00        2       <NA>
3        c       NA       NA          c
4       2%     0.02       NA       <NA>
5        3     3.00        3       <NA>
6        b       NA       NA          b
7       4%     0.04       NA       <NA>
```

Can someone help me with this task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a numeric index of elements with `%` ('i1'), then replace those having `%`  with `/100`, evaluate the string and assign the output back.  Applying `as.numeric` on the changed vector ('vv1') will result in NA for all non-numeric, similarly we can do `as.integer` on the original vector ('vv') and get all non-numeric to NA.  The elements with letters can be identified with `grepl` and use `ifelse` to convert all other elements to NA.

```
vv1 <- vv
i1 <- grep("%", vv)
library(gsubfn)
 vv1[i1] <- sapply(gsubfn(".", list(`%`="/100"), vv[i1]), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
 vv1 <- as.numeric(vv1)
vv2 <- as.integer(vv)
vv3 <- ifelse(grepl("^[A-Za-z]+$", vv), vv, NA)
data.frame(original=vv, numerics=vv1, integer=vv2, characters=vv3)
# original numerics integer characters
#1        1     1.00       1       <NA>
#2        2     2.00       2       <NA>
#3        c       NA      NA          c
#4       2%     0.02      NA       <NA>
#5        3     3.00       3       <NA>
#6        b       NA      NA          b
#7       4%     0.04      NA       <NA>
```

Comment: it worked thanks. But, I forgot something. If the original vector has also dates, what would be different if I want to create a new vector collecting the dates and combine all the vectors again to make the dataframe as before ?

Comment: In my database the equivalent of c's and b's are sentences, and does not seem to collect, those in the vector "character" in the example above.

Comment: @msh855 If there are spaces in between you may need `^[A-Za-z ]+$`